# Using select-string to output list from 1000+ files

Tags: string, powershell, select-string

I'm trying to get a specific string from a text file and output it and the filename to a separate txt file. I have tried the following but get an error message. I've looked for answers but haven't found any. Any help is appreciated.
I Should add that I'm fairly new to Powershell.

```
Select-String -Path C:\temp\test1.txt -Pattern 'batch3'|ForEach-Object {   
@' File name - {0} {1}
 ..................... '@ -f $_.Name, (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) }
| Out-File 'C:\temp\test_output.txt'
```

It works if I substitute `Select-String` for `Get-Content`. The problem then is that it takes the entire content of the file and that is not what I need.

error message:

> Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
> At line:6 char:29
> + '@ -f $*.Name, (Get-Content $*.FullName -Raw)
> +                             ~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: What is your expected output for `test_output.txt` ? I assume you're testing this to then find all files were you're pattern exists. By the way, a Here-String must end being the first character of the new line.

Comment: I agree that it's not clear what you're intending to put in the output file. It seems to me like you're using the wrong parameter names for the format operator. You can see what parameters Select-String makes available as an example by running:  `Select-String -Path C:\temp\test1.txt -Pattern 'batch3' | Select-Object -Property * -First 1`. I'm guessing you want Path and Line but it's not clear.

Comment: I apologise. The purpose is to get specific text extracted from many files in a folder and output that into a text file. I also need the name of the file either as the name or included in the file next to the text. If that makes any sense?
Something like this:
`NameOfFile        batch3
NameofFile2       batch3
NameofFile3       batch3`

Answer (score 1):

`Select-String` does not output a property `FullName`. However, there is `Path` property. Try this:

```
(Get-Content $_.Path -Raw)
```

This will fix the error, but if you want to output just a line with the string you found, not the entire file contents, remove `Get-Content` and try this:

```
Select-String -Path C:\temp\test1.txt -Pattern 'batch3'|ForEach-Object {   
@' File name - {0} {1}
 ..................... '@ -f $_.Filename, $_.Line }
| Out-File 'C:\temp\test_output.txt'
```

Comment: I noticed that using `Get-Content` instead of `Select-String` alomst does what I want. It outputs all the contents of the file instead. Maybe there is a way of using that method instead?

Comment: I tried your method and got this:

`Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\temp\test1.txt\test1.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:6 char:17
+ '@ -f $_.Name, (Get-Content (Join-Path $_.Path $_.Filename) -Raw)
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\temp\test1.txt\test1.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand`

The output looks like this:
`File name - 
.....................`

Comment: @tinman you're right, the `Join-Path` is redundant, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Almost. Now it's missing only the filename.
`Filename - 
batch3
..........................`

Comment: @tinman updated once more, it should be `$_.Filename` not `$_.Name`. Like this: `-f $_.Filename, $_.Line`

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. Now I just have to figure out how to have it go though a folder recursively, filled with these files.